# Pandas: convert column (price data) to integer

Tags: python, pandas

I've wrote up a function, its intention is to covert price data from USD, to integer. Quite simple.

The data format on each entry appears as follows (by example): $40.00, $1,100.00 etc

**Note**: it is worth mentioning that prior to any `astype()` change I make, the dtype is originally an object.

```
def convert_price(df):
    df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace('$', '') 
    df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace(',', '') # these two lines remove unwanted symbols. Leaving me with a '1100.00' for example
    df['price'] = df['price'].astype('Int64') # convert data to int. 
    return df
```

im recieving an error: object cannot be converted to an IntegerDtype.

I tried working around it as previously mentioned in a SoF question by first converting to float then int:

```
def convert_price(df):
    df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace('$', '')
    df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace(',', '')
    df['price'] = df['price'].astype('float')
    df['price'] = df['price'].astype('Int64')
    return df
```

new error :  cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64

I then searched for potential missing values:

```
df[['price']].isna().sum()
output:
price    0
dtype: int64
```

there is none found but despite the error that i get,
checking the dtype of the series returns 'int64'.

Can anyone explain to me what exactly is happening here. I'm getting errors in return of calling my function expressing it as noted above. But the output seems to have given my desired result?

EDIT: Small data sample

[image: data sample]

Comment: have you tried removing the dots (".") as well?

Comment: Please add a sample of what your date looks like

Comment: i did, yeah. My thoughts were to remove the '.' then divide by 100. but i recieved an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some values like `"$12.34"` that cannot be converted directly to int64.

So I recommend you to upcast or downcast each numbers. And upcasting can be solved by `round(decimals=FLOAT_POINT_SIZE)`.

This is an example code of upcasting.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"price": ['$40.00', '$1,100.00', '$12.34']})

df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace('$', '')
df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace(',', '')
df['price'] = df['price'].astype('float')

# ------- Added -------
df = df.round(decimals=0)
# ---------------------

df['price'] = df['price'].astype('Int64')
```

And if you see `df`,

|  | price |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 40 |
| 1 | 1100 |
| 2 | 12 |

Comment: you mean Stark. Seems like that has done the trick. I'll double check the df and see if alll is well

Comment: @DropKick Up/down-casting might be needed if some data have floating points :)

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine for me. I just used float() and int() instead of the astype() methods you were using.

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_price(df):
   df['price'] = df['price'].replace('$', '')
    df['price'] = df['price'].replace(',', '')
    df['price'] = float(df['price'])
    df['price'] = int(df['price'])
    return df

data = {
  "price": "$1,100.00"
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ["price"])
print(convert_price(df['price']))
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, however i get the following error:
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, if you just change the astype("Int64") to astype("int64") (without capital I), then it is running!

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"price" : ["$40.00", "1,000.00"]}
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   price   2 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes

def convert_price(df):
df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace('$', '')
df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace(',', '')
df['price'] = df['price'].astype('float')
df['price'] = df['price'].astype('int64') # without capital I
return df

convert_price(df_data) 

df_data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   price   2 non-null      int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 144.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is used to change the object datatype to integer and here it is saying that any symbol with the `'$'`, `','`, `'.'`, replace with nothing`('')` and change the type with astype to integer.

`#dataframe["amount"] = dataframe["amount"].str.replace('[\$\,\.]', '').astype(int)`

or try this,

```
`your_column_name = your_column_name.str.replace('[\$\,]|\.\d*', '').astype(int)`
```